# Plotting curve of f(α) = (α2 + 1)^(0.5) for t between 0 and 5, using MML to annotate graphic

Tags: r, plot, curve

I need to plot a curve of  f(α) = (α2 + 1)^(0.5) for t between 0  and 5, using MML to annotate graphic. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

So far I have two options the first shows a curve without the Function annotated at the top. This is with extra parentheses in the comments.

```
curve((x^2 + 1)^(0.5), from=0, to=5,
      xlab = expression(alpha),
      ylab = expression((alpha^2 + 1)^(0.5), # ((alpha
      main = expression(paste("Function : ",
                              f(alpha) == (alpha^2 + 1)^(0.5))))) # ))
```

Output:
[image: Curve plot of the program]

When I exclude the parentheses commented above one before the alpha and the matching one. I think I would get the annotated function at the top of the curve.

```
curve((x^2 + 1)^(0.5), from=0, to=5,
      xlab = expression(alpha),
      ylab = expression(alpha^2 + 1)^(0.5),
      main = expression(paste("Function : ",
                              f(alpha) == (alpha^2 + 1)^(0.5))))
```

The program doesn't run and gives me this error.

```
Error in expression(alpha^2 + 1)^(0.5) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may just be placement of parentheses. This should work:

```
curve((x^2 + 1)^(0.5), from=0, to=5,
      xlab = expression(alpha),
      ylab = expression((alpha^2 + 1)^(0.5)), 
      main = expression(paste("Function : ", f(alpha) == (alpha^2 + 1)^(0.5))))
```